# Verilog: How to avoid 'Redeclaration of ansi port'

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am trying to implement a start condition for i2c. And to ISim simulation I did. However, I keep getting this warning:

```
WARNING:HDLCompiler:751 - "timer_A.v" Line 40: Redeclaration of ansi port flags_timer_A is not allowed
WARNING:HDLCompiler:751 - "start_i2c.v" Line 31: Redeclaration of ansi port rst_to_tmr is not allowed
WARNING:HDLCompiler:751 - "start_i2c.v" Line 35: Redeclaration of ansi port start_done is not allowed
```

I am confused because I think I only declared *reg* **flags_timer_A** in timer_A module and only declared *regs* **rst_to_tmr** and **start_done** in start_i2c module. Also simulations shows it works but why do I keep getting thee warnings? Am I doing something not right? If so what is it? Thanks.

This is timer_A module:

```
module timer_A(
    input clk,   // which clock?
    input rst,   // sets to 0 or up counter
    //output [7:0] flags_timer_A,   // sets flag when counts to the value
    input mode,   // if mode 0, counts up to A only flags A, if 1 counts to
                        // A and B, C, D ... flags if they are not 0.
    input [15:0] count_to_A,  // counts to first value
    input [15:0] count_to_B,  // counts to second value
    input count_to_C,
    input count_to_D,
    input count_to_E,
    input count_to_F,
    input count_to_G,
    input count_to_H,
    output [7:0] flags_timer_A
);

reg [15:0] timer_A_Reg;

reg [7:0] flags_timer_A;

/*
timer_A_flag_A  = flags_timer_A[0]

timer_A_flag_B  = flags_timer_A[1]

timer_A_flag_C  = flags_timer_A[2]

timer_A_flag_D  = flags_timer_A[3] ...
*/


always @(posedge rst) begin
    flags_timer_A = 8'b0;
    timer_A_Reg = 16'b0;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        flags_timer_A = 8'b0;
        timer_A_Reg = 16'b0;
    end
    else if (!rst) begin
        if (mode == 1'b0) begin
            if (timer_A_Reg != count_to_A) begin
                timer_A_Reg <= timer_A_Reg + 1;
            end
            else begin
                flags_timer_A[0] <= 1'b1;
            end
        end
        else begin
            if (timer_A_Reg != count_to_A) begin
                timer_A_Reg = timer_A_Reg + 1;
                if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_B) begin
                    flags_timer_A[1] = 1'b1;
                end
                else if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_C) begin
                    flags_timer_A[2] = 1'b1;
                end
                else if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_D) begin
                    flags_timer_A[3] = 1'b1;
                end
                else if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_E) begin
                    flags_timer_A[4] = 1'b1;
                end
                else if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_F) begin
                    flags_timer_A[5] = 1'b1;
                end
                else if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_G) begin
                    flags_timer_A[6] = 1'b1;
                end
                else if (timer_A_Reg == count_to_H) begin
                    flags_timer_A[7] = 1'b1;
                end
            end
            else begin
                flags_timer_A[0] <= 1'b1;
            end
        end
    end
end


endmodule
```

This is start_i2c module:

```
`include "timer_A.v"
module start_i2c(
        input start,
        input [7:0] flags_timer_A,
        input clk,
        output rst_to_tmr,
        output start_done
);

reg [0:0] resetter_flag;
reg [0:0] rst_to_tmr;
reg [0:0] scl;
reg [0:0] sda;
reg [0:0] mode_to_tmr;
reg [0:0] start_done;
/*
timer_A_flag_A  = flags[0]

timer_A_flag_B  = flags[1]

timer_A_flag_C  = flags[2]

timer_A_flag_D  = flags[3] ...
*/

always @(posedge start) begin
    resetter_flag <= 1'b0;
    mode_to_tmr <= 1'b1;
    start_done <= 1'b0;
    scl <= 1'b1;
    sda <= 1'b1;
end

parameter min_SDA_on_time = 0;  
parameter min_SDA_SCL_fall_delay = 0;

always @(negedge clk)
begin: RESETTER    // this resets up when start is on immediately
    if (start && !resetter_flag) begin
        rst_to_tmr = 1'b1;
        resetter_flag = 1'b1;
    end
    else if (start && resetter_flag) begin
        rst_to_tmr <= 1'b0;
    end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (start) begin
        if (flags_timer_A[1]) begin
            sda <= 1'b0;
        end
        if (flags_timer_A[0]) begin
            scl <= 1'b0;
            start_done <= 1'b1;
        end
    end
    else begin

    end
end

always @(negedge start) begin
    resetter_flag = 1'b0;
    start_done <= 1'b0;
end

timer_A  start_timer(
    .clk             (clk),   // which clock?
    .rst             (rst_to_tmr),   // sets to 0 or up counter
    .mode     (mode_to_tmr),   // if mode 0, counts up to A only flags A, if 1 counts to
                                        // A and B, C, D ... flags if they are not 0.
    .count_to_A      (min_SDA_on_time + min_SDA_SCL_fall_delay),  // counts to first value
    .count_to_B      (min_SDA_on_time),  // counts to second value
    .count_to_C      (16'b0),
    .count_to_D      (16'b0),
    .count_to_E      (16'b0),
    .count_to_F      (16'b0),
    .count_to_G      (16'b0),
    .count_to_H      (16'b0),
    .flags_timer_A   (flags_timer_A)  // sets flag when counts to the value
);

endmodule
```

and this is the test module:

```
`include "start_i2c.v"
module start_i2c_tb(
    );

//defparam start_test.min_SDA_on_time = 16'b11001000;

//defparam start_test.min_SDA_SCL_fall_delay = 16'b01100100; 

reg [0:0] start;

wire [7:0] flags_timer_A;

reg [0:0] clk;

initial begin

    clk = 1'b0;
    start = 1'b0;
    #5 start = 1'b1;
    #40000 $finish;

end

always begin
    #1 clk = ~ clk;
end

start_i2c #(16'b11001000, 16'b01100100) start_test(
        .start          (start),
        .flags_timer_A  (flags_timer_A),
        .clk            (clk),
        .rst_to_tmr     (rst_to_tmr),
        .start_done     (start_done)
);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite simple, you are redefining an ANSI port declaration.

```
    output [7:0] flags_timer_A //Defined here as an output wire
);
...

reg [7:0] flags_timer_A; //redefined as just a register
```

If you want to declare it as an output and a register in the ANSI style, you declare it simply as:

```
    output reg [7:0] flags_timer_A //Defined here as an output reg
);
```